# Difference b/w an API and Package in JAVA?

Tags: java

What is exact difference between an API(Application Programming Interface) and a Package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're getting confused because of something like [this](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/). This is the API and contains 0 code. It describes how the packages should be laid out, but they really are different.

A package is how your organize and group your classes together. For example java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard has a package of java.awt.datatransfer.

An API is just a specification. It describes how something should work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So can we say API is just a documentation of a package/packages..?

Comment: The API is the contract which the implementation will meet. This consists of interfaces and optionally documentation. (Some API's only consist of the interfaces ;) You can't actually use documentation without interfaces (or annotations)

Answer (score 2):

An API is a specification of your application/library. For example this is the Java 6 [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

A package is a logical grouping of the classes, modules, and functionalities of your application into name spaces. Generally packages are distributed via jar files (a jar will be a collection of packages).  For instance this is a java 6 [package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Comment: I think you intended to post a link for the java 6 package?

Comment: @Geo - I did post a link for a java 6 package.